# org-mode-external-link weird search results in Tex file, "No Match"

Tags: org-mode, latex, osx, emacs24.4

Recently start exploring org-mode, find it awesome so far. 
I use Emacs+Auctex for editing my tex file and tried to create a link that links to my tex file directly to the exact line in my org file.
I found some weird results as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The ridiculous thing is the search doesn't work for \begin{} but work for \end{}. Anybody knows how to fix it? Or is this a bug?
[image: GIF]
Thanks for all the helps.

**EDIT1**: What I expect is that, when I click on the link, it will direct me to the relevant file at the EXACT line according to the search keyword after the :: after the link.
**EDIT2** GIF included.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? What do you expect to see in the output file? Also, if you have a question about search, that is probably better posted as a separate question.

Comment: @zck The two semicolons after the link is the search key, right? What I expect is that, when I click on the link, it will direct me to the relevant file at the EXACT line. The problem is the link 1 and 3 won't bring me there, "No Match", while link 2 and 4 do. Sorry for my deficiency of description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure this is related to escape characters in regexes. `\b` in a regexp means "word boundary", not "backslash, then a `b`". In text.tex, if you delete the first character of the match, so the text is `egin{Document}`, your search will work.

If you want to fix the existing link, escape the backslash:

```
file:~/target.txt::\\begin{Document}
```

This will search for a literal backslash. I'm assuming it's working for the `\end{Document}` search because I don't think there's an escape character `\e`.

Another cool thing you can do is to use org links that have short names. If you press `C-c C-l`, org mode will prompt you for a link, and then a description. In the org buffer, it'll only show the description.

Comment: Thanks so much zck! I always do C-cl to store a link and C-c C-l to insert a link, I displayed the whole link in purpose. It seems like I have to add/remove a backslash manually every time I insert a link from the stored-link-lists.